# Django now working channels with ASGI + WSGI in Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, redis, django-channels

I am trying to setup a Django + Heroku app with Channels (V.2).
I tried to follow all the tutorial but most of them are not updated.
App must use WSGI for HTTP request and ASGI for websockets requests.
So far I found that it is almost working, the last missing piece is for the websockets endpoints to be visible for web app.
At this point whenever I try to create a new websocket:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

**Here is the Settings:**

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'app_xxx.routing.application'
ASGI_THREADS = 5
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_xxx.wsgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            'hosts': [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')],
        },
    },
}
```

**Here is the Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn app_xxx.wsgi --log-file -
web2: daphne app_xxx.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channel_layer -v2
```

**Here is the asgi:**

```
import os
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app_xxx.settings")
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

**Here is the routing:**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter, ChannelNameRouter
from django.urls import path
from apps.booking.consumers import BookingConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        path('ws/booking_review/<room_name>', BookingConsumer),
    ]),
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to run the ASGI application, not channel layer. Your `ASGI_APPLICATION` setting should point to `routing.py` or you can move its contents to `asgi.py` and point to it. With your current configuration, your Procfile should look like this:

```
web: gunicorn app_xxx.wsgi --log-file -
web2: daphne app_xxx.routing:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channel_layer -v2
```

Check the docs [deployment page](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks, for the response.
Sadly this is not working either, I can see that the daphne application is up but the websockets requests never reach the web2 dyno

Comment: @Du_ actually from what I read, Heroku only allows one port open per app and that's why you can only have one web dyno. So basically the daphne service can't run on that port since it's already occupied by the gunicorn service. So your only option may be to use daphne to process both HTTP and websocket requests

Comment: That makes sense. However using only daphne with Postgres + Channels (Redis) has a mayor con. Connections are never close making making the app reach the maximum limit of 20 connections

Comment: @Du_ This part of the docs https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html talks about cases when you should manually close the connections. If you combine it correctly with `database_sync_to_async` which automatically closes the DB connection at the end of the task, it should work well without much issues

Comment: I have the same problem but I get this error `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`. Did you mean that Heroku simply doesn't allow you to run 2 ports even though you can have multiple dynos?

Comment: @Anatol you can have multiple dynos but only web dynos have open ports. So yeah, you cannot have more than one port open AFAIK